# Second nvme drive on expansion card not detected

Tags: ssd, nvme, pcie

A computer I'm trying to work on has 4 slot nvme expansion card which plugs into the PCI Express slot. I have two drives to install but it does not seem to recognise either of them. They are both WD Black. The expansion card says RHoS on it and seems to be picked up as a bridge when I run lspci. But lsblk does not show any drives.

My Ubuntu is 22.04 and up to date. The motherboard is an Asus and again up to date with firmware. I tried to see if the windows tool would update the WD Black drives but it says it can't.

There is a green light on the expansion board when there is a drive present.

I'm not quite sure where to go from here. Any suggestions on what to try next?

Comment: Look at your system startup log (watch your kernel discover the hardware) with the terminal command `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. Read `man journalctl`.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the motherboard did not support splitting of the PCI express lanes and was incompatible.